# DNS records not pointing correctly

Tags: server, dns, hosting

I have a VPS server with multiple websites on it. I have configured virtual hosts for each site directory and it works fine. I also pointed the domain to the server IP and fixed the DNS records. However, If I got to one site with www  before the domain it goes to the wrong site. for example
if I visit [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com) it goes to [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com). But if I go to site2.com it works fine... this basically happens to all sites on the server. I cannot find the issue? anyone has faced similar problems? Can someone put me in the right direction?

I can confirm that A record and NS record are pointing correctly on all domains.

Setup: Apache
Server : VPS
Server Management: Webmin

Comment: It is really hard to help you because no provide details just the statement  "I can confirm that A record and NS record are pointing correctly on all domains".

Comment: To resolve this, you/we will have to look at apache configuration

Comment: @YuriGinsburg my apologies if Im not clear enough. It turns out the issue was on my virtual host config file I did not put Server Alias. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @DusanBajic It was in apache configuration. The virtual host config file was missing the Name Server tag

Answer (score 0):

I added Server Alias in the virtual host config file.